# Sliding window with fixed duration in SQL/BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a time series `(userid, timestamp)` and I'd like to determine sessions.

A session is defined at the user level by a fixed window of 5min which starts for each new row that is not in a previous session (the window duration would ideally depend on the number of previous rows for a given user but for now I can live with a fixed window duration) e.g.

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT 0 user_id, TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01T00:00:00Z') timestamp UNION ALL -- new session
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01T00:00:00Z') UNION ALL -- new session
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01T00:04:00Z') UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01T00:06:00Z') UNION ALL -- new session
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01T00:10:00Z') UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01T00:11:00Z') UNION ALL -- new session
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01T01:00:00Z')           -- new session
)
SELECT * 
FROM sample;
```

I'm stuck since, in my reasoning, determining whether a row starts a new session depends on the "new session" column value from previous rows.

I'm targeting BigQuery so ideally it should be doable in BQ syntax.

Thanks for any help/hint!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select s.*,
       sum(case when prev_ts > timestamp_add(timestamp, interval -5 minute)
                then 0 else 1  -- "1" starts a new session
           end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as session_num
from (select s.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as prev_ts
      from sample s
     ) s
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon Linoff! The issue is that here, the session is extended and lasts for more than the fixed 5min window because we just look for another row in the last 5min. In the sample dataset, TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01T00:06:00Z') should not start a new session.

Comment: @marchelbling . . . If the sessions are limited to 5 minutes, then you have a very different problem.  Unfortunately, you'll need to loop through the data for this purpose -- the closest BigQuery comes to supporting recursive CTEs.

Comment: Indeed the problem is different and recursive in nature which is why it's bogging me. I wasn't aware that it's possible to write recursive CTE. I'll look this way, thanks!

Comment: @marchelbling . . . BigQuery doesn't support recursive CTEs, so don't get too excited.  It does offer scripts with loops, which is close in functionality for this purpose.